# Awk/Unix group by in order

Tags: unix, awk

Assume we have this text file:

```
Daisy ABC0002 1
Kevin ABC0001 2
Mike ABC0001 3
John ABC0003 4
Pete ABC0002 5
```

We try to get such a result:

```
Kevin ABC0001 2
Mike ABC0001 3
Daisy ABC0002 1
Pete ABC0002 5
John ABC0003 4
```

There is no order among names but the last column should be considered while grouping rows according to ABC000# labels. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: `sort -k2,2 -k3,3 text.file`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is correct but you might want to add an `n` after the last `3` to ensure numeric ordering in case that number can ever be greater than 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the data shown, you can simply use:

```
sort -k2,2 -k3,3
```

If there might ever be multi-digit numbers in the third column, specify numeric sorting:

```
sort -k2,2 -k3,3n
sort -k2,2 -k3n,3
```

For example, given input file:

```
Daisy ABC0002 1
Kevin ABC0001 2
Mike ABC0001 3
John ABC0003 4
Pete ABC0002 5
Hazel ABC0002 34
Sarah ABC0002 24
Alice ABC0002 11
Zoe ABC0002 9
```

Numeric sort in column 3

```
Kevin ABC0001 2
Mike ABC0001 3
Daisy ABC0002 1
Pete ABC0002 5
Zoe ABC0002 9
Alice ABC0002 11
Sarah ABC0002 24
Hazel ABC0002 34
John ABC0003 4
```

Non-numeric sort in column 3

```
Kevin ABC0001 2
Mike ABC0001 3
Daisy ABC0002 1
Alice ABC0002 11
Sarah ABC0002 24
Hazel ABC0002 34
Pete ABC0002 5
Zoe ABC0002 9
John ABC0003 4
```

Note where Zoe and Pete appear in the two outputs.